# Анонимная функция: нужно ли через use передавать $this в php 7.x?

Tags: php

Анонимная функция: нужно ли через use передавать $this в php 7.x ?

В callback функции нужно использовать метод класса, нужно ли передавать $this через  use?

```
class A {

   public $mysql = null;

   ...

   public function run(): void {
       $other = new Other;
       $other->result(function (array $data) {
           $this->mysql->query(...); // работает ли это ? с какой это версии ? и нужно ли передавать через use $this в анонимную функцию
       });

   }

}
```

$

Comment: Что за пинокио ставит - ? и почему ?

Comment: может потому что это явно в документации описано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимости нет начиная с `PHP 5.4`, при объявлении анонимной функции в контексте класса, текущий класс будет автоматически связан с ней, делая `$this` доступным внутри функции. Если вы не хотите автоматического связывания с текущим классом, используйте `static function (){...}`, это предотвратит автоматическое связывание с текущим классом.